Loading More Data in React Remix using Fetcher
I have a list of products that needs to be displayed on page load and/or after adding it in a form. Also the list has a "load more" button that can fetch more data when clicked. What's the proper way to do that in Remix? I added a fetcher.load but seems its not reflecting the changes on the list UI
Please see my code below:
export async function loader({ context }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  const offset = url.searchParams.get("offset") || 0;

  const { products, count } = await getProducts({
    limit: 10,
    offset,
  });

  return {
    products,
    count: count.aggregate?.count,
  };
}
  
export default function UploadProductsRoute() {
  let { products } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();

  const fetchers = useFetchers();

  let fetcher = useFetcher();

  const optimisticProducts = fetchers.reduce<[]>((memo, f) => {
    if (f.formData) {
      const data = (Object.fromEntries(f.formData));

      if (!products.map((e) => e.id).includes(data.id)) {
        memo.push(data);
      }
    }

    return memo;
  }, []);

  products = [...products, ...optimisticProducts];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Add products</h1>
        </div>
        <AddProductForm />
        <div>
          <h1>Products you've added</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            {products.map((product) => (
              <ProductItem key={product.id} name={product.name} description={product.description} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={() => { 
            const query = `?offset=${products.length}`;
            fetcher.load(query);
          }}>Load more</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


This might be late but hopefully this is helpful to you or others in the same situation.
https://remix.run/docs/en/main/hooks/use-fetcher#fetcherloadhref-options
According to the documentation "Because fetcher.load loads a specific URL they don't revalidate on changes to route param or URL search param". And in the documentation for shouldRevalidate we can read "fetcher.load's only revalidate by default after action submissions and explicit revalidation requests via useRevalidator".
Since your fetcher is calling the same route you are in, you might be have the problem that you need a revalidator and that changes your base data. Revalidating means that all the loaders for that route that have changes get called again. You can do const revalidator = useRevalidator(); and then in your onClick function do revalidator.revalidate(), that would rerun the loader, which should rerender your component with the new data, and not only fetch the new data.
If you placed a 'Load more' loader in a different route, you'd be able to use the fetcher.loader from the other route, while keeping the initial load here as from the useLoaderData.
Oh, and another thing: I think the query param inside the onClick needs to be the whole route (if it's a variable route you can do `const { pathname } = useLocation()" and add the query string to that)

You can use loaderData to fetch the initial page, use it as initial value in state and then use a fetcher to load more items and appending them to the state.
something like:
  const initialItems = useLoaderData();
  const fetcher = useFetcher();

  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems.items);

  // An effect for appending data to items state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!fetcher.data || fetcher.state === "loading") {
      return;
    }

    if (fetcher.data) {
      const newItems = fetcher.data.items;
      setItems((prevAssets) => [...prevAssets, ...newItems]);
    }
  }, [fetcher.data]);


This doesn't work with optimistic UI adding/delete

Nog sure how you would achieve optimistic ui in a infinite loading style apart from putting the new item at the top of the list. But that is probably a lack knowledge at my end.
